# Marking only a part of string as safe

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to show user's profile link in comment, i.e u/ali should look like a link to user's profile. but I also don't want to risk marking whole comment as safe because it will make site vulnerable to html injection so my question is this: how to mark safe only a part of a string, instead of marking the whole comment as save? 
This is the templatetags code:

```
@register.filter(name='mentioned_profiles')
def mentioned_profiles(comment):
    words = comment.split(" ")

    for word in words:
        if word[:2]=="u/":
            u = word[2:]
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=u)
                new_word = """<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/u/{}"> {}</a>""".format(user.username,user.username)
                new_word = mark_safe(new_word)
                comment = comment.replace(word,new_word)
            except:
                pass
    return comment
```

Currently, it shows the whole string, without showing the link.

Comment: Why don't you just keep the comment and the profile link as 2 different objects?

Comment: @crey4fun I think the point is that users can reference _other_ users in the text, which will get auto-linked.

Comment: I want to enable a user to mention another user in comment. The method that I'm using right now is not good for security viewpoint because anyone will become able to insert html injections in code.